# Build node relationships from a flat table

Tags: python, graph, tree

---

I have the transport network in the form of a flat table. The contents can be described as follows:

```
Start_Node,Next_Node,End_Node
10,100,1000
100,200,1000
200,1000,1000
20,1000,1000
```

I want to find all the nodes between a start_end node pair. So for above example it would look like:

```
{10_1000: [100,200,1000]
20_1000: [1000]
100_1000: [200,1000]
200_1000: [1000]}
```

Below is my attempt (I am trying to learn python, hence will appreciate any direction in that language)

```
import pandas as pd

reg = pd.read_csv('nw.csv')

start_node = reg.start.unique()
end_node = reg.end.unique()
hop_dic = {}

for i in start_node:
    for j in end_node:
        key = str(i) + " - " + str(j)
        node = []
        iter = 0
        for row in reg.itertuples():
            while(row[1]==i and row[3]==j and row[2]!=j and iter < 10):
                hop_dic[key] = node.append(row[2])
                i = row[2]
                iter = iter + 1
                print "i =",i,"j= ",j,"iter= ",iter
```

First this is slow because I am obviously running a loop and iterating all rows for all node pairs, second the node.append() doesn't work and gives all values as None in hop_dic. Iter is just to avoid infinite loops where I don't find the connected graph.

**Update**

```
import pandas as pd

reg = pd.read_csv('regularbagfwd.csv')

start_node = reg.start.unique()
end_node = reg.end.unique()
hop_dic = {}
for i in start_node:
    for j in end_node:
        key = str(i) + " - " + str(j)
        iter = 0
        reg_sub = reg.loc[reg.end == j]
        node = [0]
        while(node[-1] != j): #Checking if the last element is the end node
            for row in reg_sub.itertuples():
                if row[1]==i and row[2]==j: #last element 
                    node.append(row[2])
                    hop_dic[key] = node
                    print "i =",i,"j= ",j,"iter= ",iter,"next= ",row[2]
                    print hop_dic
                    break
                elif row[1]==i and row[2]!=j: #Not last element
                    node.append(row[2])
                    hop_dic[key] = node
                    i = row[2]
                    print "i =",i,"j= ",j,"iter= ",iter,"next= ",row[2]
                    print hop_dic
                iter = iter + 1
            if iter > 500: #I will break the while loop, untidy I know
                break
```

I got it to work where I need to add a dummy 0 to my list which I can delete later, but there has to be a much better approach.

Comment: why do you have only 10_1000 and 20_1000 in the result and not 100_1000, 200_1000 as well?

Comment: yes my bad, I will edit and add them as well.